# Double absolute value inside integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

Any ideas as to go about doing this particular integral?

$$\int\limits\limits_{-1}^{4}||x^2+x-6|-6| dx$$

I'm a bit confused as to how to consider the cases into account. My idea was to consider 4 cases and the split the limits as needed but I'm not sure if that's exactly the best approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a serious problem when you assume some certain intervals?

Comment: No. I just don't know which intervals to properly use. I could do it easily if it was a single absolute value. The double is throwing me off.

Comment: Well $x^2 + x - 6 = (x+3)(x-2) $ so it's easy to find where to split the limits.

Comment: Yes I got that but I'm still confused. So like I go from -1 to -3 and from -3 to 2 but how do the signs work out then? Cuz like that's the inner absolute value. What about the outer one?

Comment: x = -1 => both negative. At x = 0 the whole thing is 0.  For 0 to 2, inside is positive and whole thing is negative.  >2  the inside and the whole thing is positive.

Comment: Hmm okay. Let me try :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While $x\in[-1,2]$ so $|x^2+x-6|=-x^2-x+6$ and so $$||x^2+x-6|-6|\to|-x^2-x|=|x^2+x|$$ and when $x\in[2,4]$ so $|x^2+x-6|=+x^2+x-6$ and so $$||x^2+x-6|-6|\to|x^2+x-12|=|(x+4)(x-3)|$$

As the integrand is a integrable function on $[-1,4]$ so we get $$\int_{-1}^4||x^2+x-6|-6|dx=\int_{-1}^2|x^2+x|dx+\int_{2}^4|(x+4)(x-3)|dx$$

Now consider the same way for each of integrals above.

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty: I hope I helped. :-)